# Como usar uma variável para indexar um item em uma lista - Python

Tags: python, lista, for

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto, tenho uma lista e preciso buscar alguns itens específicos dentro dela.

```
head_list = ['Nome', 'Data', 'Cirurgia', 'Diagnostico pré operatório', 
            'Cirurgião', 'Cirurgião Procto', '2-Cirurgião', '1-Auxiliar', 
            '2-Auxiliar', '1-Auxiliar procto', 'Instrumentador']


print(head_list[1], head_list[2], head_list[4], head_list[5])
```

Não quero ficar repetindo código, então pensei em montar um for e usar uma variável (como um contador por exemplo) para mudar o valor do 'head_list[ ***item*** ]' que quero dentro da lista

```
for i in range(0, 9):
   print(head_list['*usar a variável para mudar esse valor*'])
```

Sou novo na programação, não sei se essa forma seria correta...gostaria de uma orientação pra fazer essa ideia funcionar

Answer (score -4):

```
head_list = [
    'Nome', 'Data', 'Cirurgia', 'Diagnostico pré operatório',
    'Cirurgião', 'Cirurgião Procto', '2-Cirurgião', '1-Auxiliar',
    '2-Auxiliar', '1-Auxiliar procto', 'Instrumentador'
]

def hl(indices):
    for x in indices:
        print(head_list[x], end=' ')
        
hl([1, 2, 4, 5]) # Data Cirurgia Cirurgião Cirurgião Procto
```